# employer lying about not selling the company

Tags: employer

the employer i work for has stated they are not selling the dealership but there are very strong rumors and someone that works for another dealer that stated they are buying our dealership. the regional manager came in and had a meeting stating that they are not selling, our manager just quit out of the blue, and there have been corporate contractors on the property marking areas for what looks like financing. also the office clerks came through marking and taking inventory of all company owned tools and equipment. just curious if they do end up selling and have lied to us this whole time if there is a case or not.

Answer (score 2):

It depends where you are located. If in the U.S., this is likely completely legal.

If it walks like a duck and talks like a duck... Yes, they are probably selling the business.

They're lying so they will still have employees during this transition. If they told everyone that in a couple of weeks a new owner will be overseeing things at that they cannot guarantee any of you will be kept on, then everyone would quit and go find new employment. Your manager caught wind of what was happening and did exactly that, maybe you should too.

Comment: im in california.

Comment: And I'm betting you're an at-will employee as well? Which would mean they can terminate your employment for almost any reason.

Comment: basically yes, im a mechanic.